# How to make a <a> tag not inherit width from <span>

Tags: html, css

I have a simple warning message:

HTML

```
<span id="j_idt68" class="aviso">
<a href="MEU LINK">message</a></span>​
```

CSS

```
span.aviso a {
    padding:20px 35px;
    background: rgb(255, 174, 174);
    background: rgba(255, 174, 174, 0.3);
    border:1px solid #FF1C1C;                 
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#FF0000; 
    text-align: center;
    opacity:1;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    display:block;
}​
```

I declared the width of the span to be 960px because I want the message to be centered but I don't want the rounded rectangle site to be 960px, I would like it to adjust it's width according to the size of the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` element isn’t inheriting the width; instead, you are setting `display: block` on it, making its width the entire available width. You need to separate the settings so that the `span` aligns text lines inside it and the `a` element is `inline-block` (or defaulted to `inline`, but then you have line height problems). Like this:

```
span.aviso { 
    display: block;
    width: 960px; 
    text-align: center;
}
span.aviso a {
    padding: 20px 35px;
    background: rgb(255, 174, 174);
    background: rgba(255, 174, 174, 0.3);
    border:1px solid #FF1C1C;                 
    border-radius:10px;
    color:#FF0000; 
    opacity:1;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;` on the anchor selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/fZA8b/